# split each line of text into words and set them into 2d array in C

Tags: arrays, c

I am working on an exercise. I have a text file like:

```
and a b c
and f e
not c x
```

I need to split the words and store them into a 2-dimensional array like this:

```
buf[0][0]=and
buf[0][1]=a
buf[0][2]=b
buf[0][3]=c
buf[1][0]=and
buf[1][1]=f
buf[1][2]=e
buf[2][0]=not
buf[2][1]=c
buf[2][2]=x
```

If there is any way to made this, please let me know.

```
FILE *fp;
int countLines=0;
char ch,**buf,*ptr;




fp=fopen("data3.txt","r");
if(fp==NULL){
   printf("Empty file.\n");
}

for (ch = getc(fp); ch != EOF; ch = getc(fp)) 
    if (ch == '\n') 
        countLines = countLines + 1; 
printf("lines=%d\n",countLines);

rewind(fp);

char text[countLines][20];

int row = 0;

while(row < countLines && fgets(text[row], sizeof(text[0]), fp) != NULL)
    ++row;
char  xw[row][5];
for (int i= 0; i != row; ++i){ 
    //fputs(text[i], stdout);
    ptr=strtok(text[i]," ");
    int j=0;
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        printf ("%s\n",ptr);
        xw[i][j]=ptr;
        ptr = strtok (NULL, " ");
        j++;
    }
    j=0;
}
```

I know that the code under `fputs` is wrong, but I can't make this!

Comment: xw is an array of pointers, so needs to be char* instead of char.

Comment: @stark thank you very much I was stuck there for  hours